# SQL Server 2012 enable remote access without restart

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a website that runs on Microsoft server (I have a remote desktop connection) with the SQL database. I want to enable remote access to the SQL database, without restarting the service. Is that possible?

Comment: If you make a change to the config of SQL Server you'll have to restart the service for it to take affect. Sometimes the agent too

Comment: Thank you. What is the best way for me to restart the service? I have never used windows server before. With Linux/MySQL I know that I could painlessly restart the service. Is it the same with windows server and SQL. Do I run a risk of messing everything up?